# It it possible for Capybara to check if an HTML element is covered via an overflow: hidden parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

If an HTML button overflow's beyond an ancestor's bounds, and that ancestor has `overflow: hidden`, then a user cannot click the button. Is it possible to catch errors like this using Capybara? Element.visible? returns true in this case, even though the user cannot see/interact with the element.

Answer (score 1):

There's no boolean method to check whether it's overlapped, but it should fail if you try to interact with it (click it), which is what you should be doing anyway in a feature test (rather than testing for visibility of the button).